# Building a frequency count map in groovy.

Tags: groovy

I have an array and i want to build a map out of it recording the frequency of elements in the array. So for the example below the map = [15:2, 16:1] is what it will look like. How do I do this in Groovy ?

```
static void doSomething()
    {
        def a = [15,16,15]
        def map = []
        a.each{
            k,v-> 
            if(map.contains(it)) 
            map.putAt k, v++
            else
            map.putAt k, 1;
        }

        println map
    }
```

Comment: As far as what's wrong with your code.  First, map should initialize with [:], if you want it to be a map.  2nd, you can't put v++ into map, that's the values 15++, 16++, etc.  use map.put k, map.get(k)++

Answer (score 14):

In Groovy 1.8 or higher,

```
assert [15, 16, 15].countBy { it } == [15: 2, 16: 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could modify your code to be the following:

```
void doSomething() {
        def a = [15,16,15]
        def map = [:]  //1
        a.each {  //2
            if(map.containsKey(it)) map[it] = map[it] + 1  //3
            else map[it] = 1;
        }

        println map
}
```

This fixes a few things:

1. map needs to be initiated with colon between braces, as notes by Bill James in comments.
2. can't use a 2-parameter version of `each` on an arraylist
3. postfix increment won't result in incremented value being saved; Also, explicit `putAt` call is fine, but it's there to provide the overloaded `[key] = val` syntax which is more expressive.

All that said, I'm assuming this is a coding exercise to learn groovy.  doelleri's answer is more succinct and uses the tools provided, so in a real-world situation, I'd go with that.